# cannot put content in container in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap. I put the content in a container in Bootstrap. But somehow a part of the content (see picture container_fail) is not in a container. Please see picture (container_fail) Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong to avoid this? Maybe it is something very stupid that I cannot solve. I would appreciate your help!

**here is my code so far:**

```css
.container#parallex {
  background: black;
}

/* Parallex*/

#plx {
  background: url(/images/pic4.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wtitle {
  padding: 150px 20px;
}

.wtitle h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
}

#treppen {
  height: 700px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#text5 h1 {
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.row img {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <section id="plx">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="wtitle text-center text-light">
    <h2>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
    </h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="treppen">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="text-muted" id="text5">
    <h1 class="text-muted">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt eveniet perspiciatis dicta ipsam iusto voluptatem ipsa dolore praesentium, incidunt minima mollitia, suscipit optio architecto deleniti unde earum doloribus corrupti sed atque voluptate sit in. Dolore assumenda quia iste quas, minima optio ex! Commodi, aliquam totam est quasi dolorum mollitia inventore quae, nostrum animi, dicta ut atque modi eum quod. Laborum illo harum, libero commodi mollitia architecto eos quas velit est! Porro doloremque unde ad. Eaque, excepturi? Error officia expedita nisi ipsa aut quae, adipisci voluptates sapiente esse obcaecati velit, necessitatibus eos, rem ab ut cupiditate non odio perspiciatis ducimus veritatis?.
    </h1>
    <h1 class="text-muted" style="padding-top: 0px; font-weight: bold">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit:
    </h1>
    <div class="row subsection">
     <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
      <div class="web">
       <img alt="Icono Web" class="lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/images/pic5.jpg" height="40" src="/images/pic5.jpg" width="48">
       <h6>
        Test
       </h6>
       <p class="text__small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus ipsam magni recusandae illum neque ratione quisquam assumenda ad? Placeat, consequuntur..
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
      <div class="web">
       <img alt="Icono servidor" class="lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/img/w_server.svg" height="40" src="/img/w_server.svg" width="48">
       <h6>
        Test
       </h6>
       <p class="text__small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, harum. Nam sit nihil excepturi sint ad sequi nobis dolorem cumque.
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
      <div class="web">
       <img alt="Icono app" class="apps--img lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/img/w_apps.svg" height="40" src="/img/w_apps.svg" width="48">
       <h6>
        Test
       </h6>
       <p class="text__small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, molestiae velit. Debitis adipisci aut ducimus labore nulla fuga alias itaque!
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
      <div class="web">
       <img alt="Icono integración" class="lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/img/w_integration.svg" height="40" src="/img/w_integration.svg" width="48">
       <h6>
        Test
       </h6>
       <p class="text__small">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo fugit accusantium natus tenetur dicta perspiciatis dolor et sed quidem modi!
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

[image: container_fail]

Comment: h1 margion: 0; padding: 0; 
and h1 tag must be only one on the page! If this was helpful, I can leave an answer

Comment: The highlit part is affected by `#text5 h1`'s padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have change `h1` tag to `p` tag for paragraph and also `remove css` form h1 tag.

```css
.container#parallex {
  background: black;
}

/* Parallex*/

#plx {
  background: url(/images/pic4.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wtitle {
  padding: 150px 20px;
}

.wtitle h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
}

#treppen {
  height: 700px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

#text5 h1 {
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  /*padding: 40px 40px;*/
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.row img {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <section id="plx">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="wtitle text-center text-light">
          <h2>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
          </h2>
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>
       <section id="treppen">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="text-muted" id="text5">
          <p class="text-muted">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt eveniet perspiciatis dicta ipsam iusto voluptatem ipsa dolore praesentium, incidunt minima mollitia, suscipit optio architecto deleniti unde earum doloribus corrupti sed atque voluptate sit in. Dolore assumenda quia iste quas, minima optio ex! Commodi, aliquam totam est quasi dolorum mollitia inventore quae, nostrum animi, dicta ut atque modi eum quod. Laborum illo harum, libero commodi mollitia architecto eos quas velit est! Porro doloremque unde ad. Eaque, excepturi? Error officia expedita nisi ipsa aut quae, adipisci voluptates sapiente esse obcaecati velit, necessitatibus eos, rem ab ut cupiditate non odio perspiciatis ducimus veritatis?.
          </p>
          <h1 class="text-muted" style="padding-top: 0px; font-weight: bold">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit:
          </h1>
          <div class="row subsection">
           <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
            <div class="web">
             <img alt="Icono Web" class="lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/images/pic5.jpg" height="40" src="/images/pic5.jpg" width="48">
             <h6>
              Test
             </h6>
             <p class="text__small">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus ipsam magni recusandae illum neque ratione quisquam assumenda ad? Placeat, consequuntur..
             </p>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
            <div class="web">
             <img alt="Icono servidor" class="lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/img/w_server.svg" height="40" src="/img/w_server.svg" width="48">
             <h6>
              Test
             </h6>
             <p class="text__small">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, harum. Nam sit nihil excepturi sint ad sequi nobis dolorem cumque.
             </p>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
            <div class="web">
             <img alt="Icono app" class="apps--img lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/img/w_apps.svg" height="40" src="/img/w_apps.svg" width="48">
             <h6>
              Test
             </h6>
             <p class="text__small">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, molestiae velit. Debitis adipisci aut ducimus labore nulla fuga alias itaque!
             </p>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
            <div class="web">
             <img alt="Icono integración" class="lozad" data-loaded="true" data-src="/img/w_integration.svg" height="40" src="/img/w_integration.svg" width="48">
             <h6>
              Test
             </h6>
             <p class="text__small">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo fugit accusantium natus tenetur dicta perspiciatis dolor et sed quidem modi!
             </p>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>
```

Comment: it helped! do you know why the section `<div class="row subsection">` is not responsive?

Comment: `<div class="row subsection">` inner div you want to full width so you need to change inner div class to `col-sm-3 col-12 center`  this class make this div full width in small device.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the h1 tag in to a paragraph, as it makes no sense to have such a long headline here.

So instead of:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text-muted" id="text5">
       **<h1 class="text-muted">**
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt eveniet perspiciatis dicta ipsam iusto voluptatem ipsa dolore praesentium, incidunt minima mollitia, suscipit optio architecto deleniti unde earum doloribus corrupti sed atque voluptate sit in. Dolore assumenda quia iste quas, minima optio ex! Commodi, aliquam totam est quasi dolorum mollitia inventore quae, nostrum animi, dicta ut atque modi eum quod. Laborum illo harum, libero commodi mollitia architecto eos quas velit est! Porro doloremque unde ad. Eaque, excepturi? Error officia expedita nisi ipsa aut quae, adipisci voluptates sapiente esse obcaecati velit, necessitatibus eos, rem ab ut cupiditate non odio perspiciatis ducimus veritatis?.
       </h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

better use

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text-muted" id="text5">
       **<p class="text-muted">**
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt eveniet perspiciatis dicta ipsam iusto voluptatem ipsa dolore praesentium, incidunt minima mollitia, suscipit optio architecto deleniti unde earum doloribus corrupti sed atque voluptate sit in. Dolore assumenda quia iste quas, minima optio ex! Commodi, aliquam totam est quasi dolorum mollitia inventore quae, nostrum animi, dicta ut atque modi eum quod. Laborum illo harum, libero commodi mollitia architecto eos quas velit est! Porro doloremque unde ad. Eaque, excepturi? Error officia expedita nisi ipsa aut quae, adipisci voluptates sapiente esse obcaecati velit, necessitatibus eos, rem ab ut cupiditate non odio perspiciatis ducimus veritatis?.
       </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove #treppen css 
[image: refer image]

```css
 <style>
        .container#parallex {
            background: black;
        }

        /* Parallex*/

        #plx {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            background: url("images/1.jpg");
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .wtitle {
            padding: 150px 20px;
        }

        .wtitle h2 {
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1;
            letter-spacing: -.05rem;
        }

        #treppen {
            /* height: 700px; */
            /* background: #f5f5f5; */
        }

        #text5 h1 {
            line-height: 1.6;
            letter-spacing: .1px;
            padding: 40px 40px;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        .navbar-brand img {
            height: 30px;
            width: 30px;
        }

        .row img {
            height: 24px;
            width: 24px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <section id="plx">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="wtitle text-center text-light">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="treppen">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-muted" id="text5">
                    <h1 class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt eveniet
                        perspiciatis dicta ipsam iusto voluptatem ipsa dolore praesentium, incidunt minima mollitia,
                        suscipit optio architecto deleniti unde earum doloribus corrupti sed atque voluptate sit in.
                        Dolore assumenda quia iste quas, minima optio ex! Commodi, aliquam totam est quasi dolorum
                        mollitia inventore quae, nostrum animi, dicta ut atque modi eum quod. Laborum illo harum,
                        libero commodi mollitia architecto eos quas velit est! Porro doloremque unde ad. Eaque,
                        excepturi? Error officia expedita nisi ipsa aut quae, adipisci voluptates sapiente esse
                        obcaecati velit, necessitatibus eos, rem ab ut cupiditate non odio perspiciatis ducimus
                        veritatis?.</h1>
                    <h1 class="text-muted" style="padding-top: 0px; font-weight: bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit:</h1>
                    <div class="row subsection">
                        <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
                            <div class="web">
                                <img class="lozad" data-src="images/13.jpg" width="48" height="40" alt="Icono Web"
                                    src="images/13.jpg" data-loaded="true">
                                <h6>Test</h6>
                                <p class="text__small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus
                                    ipsam magni recusandae illum neque ratione quisquam assumenda ad? Placeat,
                                    consequuntur..
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
                            <div class="web">
                                <img class="lozad" data-src="images/13.jpg" width="48" height="40" alt="Icono servidor"
                                    src="images/13.jpg" data-loaded="true">
                                <h6>Test</h6>
                                <p class="text__small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                    Excepturi, harum. Nam sit nihil excepturi sint ad sequi nobis dolorem cumque.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
                            <div class="web">
                                <img class="apps--img lozad" data-src="images/13.jpg" width="48" height="40" alt="Icono app"
                                    src="images/13.jpg" data-loaded="true">
                                <h6>Test</h6>
                                <p class="text__small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt,
                                    molestiae velit. Debitis adipisci aut ducimus labore nulla fuga alias itaque!
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12-sm col-3 center">
                            <div class="web">
                                <img class="lozad" data-src="images/13.jpg" width="48" height="40" alt="Icono integración"
                                    src="images/13.jpg" data-loaded="true">
                                <h6>Test</h6>
                                <p class="text__small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                    Explicabo fugit accusantium natus tenetur dicta perspiciatis dolor et sed quidem
                                    modi!
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```